# How to change the Next/Cancel button captions on a custom page?

Tags: inno-setup

How to change the Next/Cancel button captions on a custom page ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = YourPageName.ID then begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall);  
//or := 'YourNewNextButtonText' or := ExpandConstant('{cm:YourCmTitleForNext}')
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:YourCmTitleForCancel}');
  end; //begin + end to make changes only for this single page
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget to change them back again when it's not your page ID.